# cannot get current_url correctly

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get current url using selenium. Here is my code:

```
#landing on page
driver.get("http://web.archive.org/web/20200922013649/https://www.shadesofstone.com/hardscape/flagstones-more/landscape-galore.html")

#get current url
main_link = driver.current_url
print(main_link)
```

but I am getting only this:

```
https://www.shadesofstone.com/hardscape/flagstones-more/landscape-galore.html
```

instead of this

```
http://web.archive.org/web/20200922013649/https://www.shadesofstone.com/hardscape/flagstones-more/landscape-galore.html
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: What action you have performed to get this? can you post the entire code?

Comment: Please share ALL your code. As mentioned by Kunduk currently your question is missing basic debugging details

Comment: Hi, can you please check now. @Prophet

Comment: Hm... I don't know. Seems like the internal implementation is removing all possible prefix parts coming before `https://www` since normally URL contains only ones the `https://www` substring and this should be the beginning of the URL however I couldn't find that in the internal implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug with `driver.current_url`.

Here's a workaround you can use: `driver.execute_script("return document.location.href;")`

```py
driver.get("http://web.archive.org/web/20200922013649/https://www.shadesofstone.com/hardscape/flagstones-more/landscape-galore.html")

main_link = driver.execute_script("return document.location.href;")
print(main_link)
```